# Declined flag after edit needs to be fixed for ever

Tags: support, edits, flags, declined-flags

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62454253/android-studio-display-long-in-button-text) which **Needs details or clarity** (the reason of my flag), and my flag was declined.

The problem is, I flagged the question before it was edited ([see edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62454253/revisions)) the very first version of the question was only:

> *How would I go about displaying a Long or Int inside of a button element's text field (or a TextView)? Would the same method work for
> displaying a String inside the text field? Thanks.*

I cannot ignore a question like this without flagging it, but unfortunately, it was declined after vote without seeing the edit history. Reviewers should be more attentive. I hope that my issue would be fixed, and I hope to find an ultimate solution so that this very common problem does not repeat itself with other users.

Comment: What did you flag it for?

Comment: @Nick Needs details or clarity

Comment: Meh, these things happen, you could've followed the post and gone back and retracted it after it was edited. Besides, a single declined flag won't harm you in any way, just forget about it and move on, not the end of the day.

Comment: It looks like no moderator was involved to decline your flag https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/26450143 you just happened to be unlucky in the chain of events https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62454253/timeline, the reviewers in the end had to choose leave open once the edit was in. And that outcome is opposite of what your flag suggested.

Comment: @rene Bit disappointing that first Leave Open vote was _before_ it got edited :sigh:

Comment: @Nick yeah, don't get me started ...

Comment: Don't worry too much about declined close flags after edits. After you get 3K rep it won't happen anymore, before that you _could_ follow every post you flag and retract flags in case of substantial improvements (which is also a good thing to do if you can cast close votes) but that's not worth the effort imo.

Answer (score 13):

> Reviewers should be more attentive.

They were. Some of them reviewed a close review task and saw a reasonable question so they voted to leave open. Leave open was the correct action after the post was edited. Reviewers have to decide on which action to take based on the content the post is in. Not on what the post was when you flagged it. Reviewers don't know you flagged it, nor when you flagged it so they can't reason about how their review will affect your flag status.

> I hope that my issue would be fixed,

It will not and doesn't need to be fixed. A declined flag now and then is all in the game.

> and I hope to find an ultimate solution so that this very common problem does not repeat itself with other users.

It can't be solved without sacrificing quality / open the system for gaming / confuse  our reviewers even more.

Thank you for flagging and participating in keeping SO clean and useful with great content. I'm sorry your flag got declined, there is no viable option to prevent that, except that you can [follow the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network) you flagged and then revisit when an edit comes in so you can re-evaluate your flag and retract when needed.